# Netbeans jUnit 4 - Java EE API is missing on project classpath

Tags: maven, testing, netbeans, junit, junit4

I have clear maven web app project. 
I add jUnit to pom.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>         
    </dependency>  

</dependencies>
```

I have one very simple Servlet in my app.
I want to generate jUnit 4 test for this servlet.
So I click on the Servlet package > Tools > Create Test.
After this I get test class with method.

```
public void testProcessRequest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("processRequest");
    HttpServletRequest request = null;
    HttpServletResponse response = null;
    MyServlet instance = new MyServlet(); // This is the problem 
    instance.processRequest(request, response);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");

}
```

MyServlet is underline and the error is : "Java EE API is missing on the project classpath".

I tried modify the scopes of dependencies in pom but problem still exist.

Comment: Based on the name you have to be aware of that API is just an interface which must have an implementation which simply is missing.

Comment: There are no compilation problem, app. works fine, and I saw javaee-web-api-6.0.jar in Dependecies. The only problem is with tests.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a container which contains an implementation of the EE Client part. I didn't said that you have problems with compiling. This looks like you are trying to create integration tests which have to run inside a kind of container (TomEE etc.) which needs an implementation for those EE API parts.

Comment: Yes this is integration tests. I thought that netbeans can easly generate something like a test stub for jUnit 4. I'm interesting both integration and unit test. ( Im using both TomCat and Glassfish which are default for NetBeans 7.2.1 )